# Theming Node Edit Forms

Tags: 7, nodes, theming

I'm having an issue with theming our node edit forms. We are converting a Drupal 6 theme to Drupal 7 and its causing a lot of problems.

In our template.php we have

```
function dupublic_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
    return array(
            'page_node_form' => array(
                    'arguments' => array('form' => NULL),
                    'template' => 'page-node-form',
                    'render_element' => 'form',
            ),
    );
}
```

This successfully points Drupal at 'page-node-form.tpl.php'

Our goal is to pull out some fields into labeled areas to make our editor's job easier. We had a more complex layout, but I've simplified it for the following example.
In page-node-form.tpl.php I have the following:

```
<div class='title'>
    <?php print drupal_render($form['title']);?>
</div>
<div id='custom-form'>
    <?php print drupal_render_children($form); ?>
</div>
```

This, however, does not work. `$form` does not appear to exist, and `dpm($form);` displays as an empty array. We do not get any form fields *at all* - unless I remove everything from the tpl file, then I get some sort of default form display, which doesn't make sense. If the tpl file is empty no form should be displayed, but everything I am reading states that `drupal_render($form['field'])` and `drupal_render_children($form)` should work! They aren't!

This is what is rendered on page load:

```
<form class="node-form node-page-form" action="/node/5/edit" method="post" id="page-node-form" accept-charset="UTF-8" data-thmr="thmr_33">
    <div>
        <div class="title" data-thmr="thmr_32"></div>
        <div id="custom-form" data-thmr="thmr_32"></div>
    </div>
</form>
```

As you can see, no form fields!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `template.php` the [hook_theme](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_theme/7) implementation should look like that:

```
function dupublic_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return array(
    'page_node_form' => array(
      'template' => 'page-node-form',
      'render element' => 'form',
    ),
  );
}
```

Notice that in the return array `'render element'` key is without underscore, and there is no `'arguments'` key in Drupal 7 version of `hook_theme()`. It is replaced by `'variables'` key, but the documentation states that:

> Each information array must contain either a 'variables' element or a
>   'render element' element, but not both. Use 'render element' if you
>   are theming a single element or element tree composed of elements,
>   such as a form array, a page array, or a single checkbox element.

Another point that I notice is, that you used in your `page-node-form.tpl.php` file statements like:

```
<?php print drupal_render($form['title']);?>
```

I prefer to print the elements like that, and recommend you to do so:

```
<?php print render($form['title']);?>
```

It's a new function in Drupal 7 and it calls `drupal_render()` but first checks if the passed element is an array and also calls `show()` function if the element is set hidden.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! Mysteriously when I reverted all my changes to where I started it began to work. I have no idea what the problem was! :(

Comment: Your answer helped a lot. Can you tell me how to display error messages in the page? `print $messages` did not work here.

Comment: @DushyantJoshi you should put `print $messages` into `page.tpl.php` file (for your administration theme, if your node add/edit forms are set to open in admin theme)