# Attributes in table in custom content type form

Tags: forms, entities

I am creating a custom content type named "Invoice".
 This content type is having attributes like Company Name (entity reference to company content type), Bill details, tax details and calculations. 
Can you please suggest how can I get elements/attributes like shown in an image in custom content type add new content form? [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[field_collection](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection) module allows you to add a field (Bill details) that contains a collection of fields (Amount, Service Tax, VAT, etc.). Set it to accept multiple values and you get a list like the one shown in the photo.

Comment: I tried field_collect. Its not generating the table. If you have any demo link, can you please share?

Comment: Yes, it's not straightforward. Make sure you have a look at the [documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/1353926).
`After the field collection field is created it's managed under from Home > Administration > Structure > Field collections. This is where fields are added to the field collections created in the Manage fields tab.`

Answer (score 1):

You will need to override the node form template for your invoice content type with a custom template in your theme. More info -> [Theming Node Forms in Drupal 7](https://www.drupal.org/node/1092122) and [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/76708/theming-node-edit-forms)

In your template you'd build a layout for your fields and output form fields in place like this

```
<?php print drupal_render($form['fieldname']);?>
```